# Session Variables Issue in IE8 and Classic ASP

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

So I have a website featuring a stock management system, this contains a table that displays various stock and inventory information.

When an "images" link is clicked, the Session variable for images is switched between "show" and "hide" and the page is then reloaded with the updated variable and either showing or hidden images for each product.

This works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Opera (all tested thoroughly) but does not work at all in IE8.

Normally I would blame my code but clearly this is a pure browser compatibility issue which is really throwing me as i didn't realise ASP and VBScript really needed to be altered to work on different browsers.

I have attached the code that toggles the session variable below anyway but I doubt it is linked to the issue.

```
images = Request.QueryString("images")

If images <> "" Then
    If images = "show" Then
        Session("images") = "Show"
    ElseIf images = "hide" Then
        Session("images") = "Hide"
    End If
End If
```

An example of the problem goes as follows:

I display some items and click "hide images", the images then hide..

I then reload the page and the images are showing again and the Session variable has changed back to "show" despite there being NOWHERE in the code that specifies to return back to the previous value (checked with Ctrl + F for keyword "images")

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem where Session variables act in unusual ways specifically in IE, or can suggest a solution?

Thanks, Josh

Comment: Would the down-voter explain why, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks, Josh - here you go.

You can use the `Server.URLEncode()` (classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/…) method to counter this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The server side code of Classic ASP is browser independent.  What's more likely to be a problem is the way you make the section show or hide.

Check your code and pay special attention to the method you've used to actually do the showing and hiding.  Check out the styles for the block that contains your product using the developer tools in IE8.

Comment: I've done a bit more digging and have found a possible issue where Sessions and Cookies are not stored in sites with underscores in the address (as mine does) so am looking into that currently.. Agree though that it really has to be in the coding method

Answer (score 1):

After further research I have found why my page is not working correctly via a Microsoft support page.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316112

The fact that my page URL had an underscore in it caused Session variables and Cookies to not be saved.

Hope this helps others in the future

Josh

Comment: You can use the `Server.URLEncode()` (http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-decode-an-encoded-url.html) method to counter this problem.

Comment: Thanks Paul, just what I needed. If you want you can put this comment in as a separate response and I'll mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to retrieve/show session values within same page that you are assigning session values? I'm asking just to be sure because it takes one round trip to the server to save those session values.